# No cyrillic letters in Qt 4.8.6 / Linux Mint

Tags: c++, linux, qt, linux-mint, cyrillic

I can't read or write any Russian text in a program written on Qt. All labels on Russian are blank, typing Cyrillic letters in QLineEdit has no effect.

Note all other programs works with Russian fine, even Qt Creator itself. In form design mode all labels are OK, but they disappear when I run a program.

Also Qt Linguist doesn't show Russian text

Image below shows a test program: Second line label contains Russian text, and QLineEdit at end too.

[image]

I tried `qtconfig`. It works, font changes, but no Russian letters appeared

Configuration:

```
resu@resu-desktop ~ $ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.13.0-24-generic (buildd@batsu) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu      
4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014
```

`/etc/lsb-release`:

```
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17
DISTRIB_CODENAME=qiana
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17 Qiana"
```

Qt: 4.8.6

`.qmake.cache`:

```
CONFIG +=  debug largefile stl precompile_header mmx 3dnow sse sse2 
sse3 ssse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 avx dylib create_prl link_prl depend_includepath
fix_output_dirs QTDIR_build
```

Comment: how about copy paste in both directions? When you debug do you see proper Russian strings? Do you use some custom font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `QFontDialog` and found that Qt has only ten ugly raster fonts, with `Bitstream Character` as default. [This](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/35653-QT-4-7-looks-ugly-on-GNOME!?p=165121#post165121) topic said I need rebuild Qt with `-fontconfig` option. Also I installed other recommended [Qt for X11 requirements](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/requirements-x11.html).

First `./configure` attempt reported a problem

```
QTextCodec: using KOI8-R, probe failed (e0 ce ru)
```

and [this](http://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=23586&view=findpost&p=232032) topic helped me:

```
$ localedef --no-archive -c -f KOI8-R -i ru_RU ru_RU.KOI8-R
```

My final script to build is:

```
sudo apt-get install  libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev\
libx11-dev libxcursor-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxft-dev\
libxi-dev libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev

localedef --no-archive -c -f KOI8-R -i ru_RU ru_RU.KOI8-R

./configure -debug -opensource -shared -qt-sql-psql -nomake demos\
-nomake examples -gtkstyle -xrender -xrandr -xcursor -xfixes -fontconfig

make

sudo make install
```